# Excessive pending callback while loading video in Webview in React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, webview, wistia

I have the functionality Where I am loading the Wistia Video in Webview.
This is what I am doing in React Native.

The functionality works well when the video is loaded in portrait but when the video is moved to the landscape mode via native controller and when closed the UI gets distorts and causes the exception as below.

> excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code: {"17417":{},"17418":{},"17419":{},"17420":{"module":"UIManager","method":"measureLayout"},"17421":{"module":"UIManager","method":"measureLayout"},"17422":{},"17423":{},"17424":{},"17425":{},"17426":{},"17427":{},"17430":{},"17431":{},"17432":{},"17433":{},"17434":{},"17435":{},"17436":{},"17437":{},"17438":{},"17439":{},"17440":{},"17441":{},"17442":{"module":"UIManager","method":"measureLayout"},"17443":{"module":"UIManager","method":"measureLayout"},"17444":{},"17445":{},"17446":{},"17447":{},"17448":{},"17449":{},"17450":{},"17451":{},"17454":{},"17455":{},"17456":{},"17457":{},"17458":{"module":"UIManager","method":"measureLayout"},"17459":{"module":"UIManager","method":"measureLayout"},"17460":{},"17461":{},"17462":{},"17463":{},"17464":{},"17465":{},"17466":{},"17467":{},"17468":{},"17469":{},"17470":{},"...(truncated keys)...":451}

The solutions to this suggests that there can be multiple async calls etc. which is not the case here.
The simple flow is as below

**FlatList> WebView>Wistia link> turning to landscape mode> closing the video> Exception thrown.**